# Did Kylo Ren ever actually start training with Snoke?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

Is there any canon reference that Kylo Ren actually started learning from Snoke?

We hear Snoke saying something like:

> It's time to finish your training.

But he is *resuming* his training of Ren or did he never train him before, giving credit for what he learned from Luke?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He started training with Luke. From WGA script:

> HAN
>   There was nothing we could've done.
>   (hard for him to say)
>   There was too much Vader in him.
>   LEIA
>   **That's why I wanted him to train with Luke**.
>   **I just never should have sent him away**.
>   That's when I lost him. That's when I lost you both.

In addition, in the Novelization, Snoke explicitly discusses with Kylo Ren that he sculpted him BASED on his training with Luke.

> "It is your teachings that make me strong, Supreme Leader"
>   Snoke demurred.  "It is far more than that.  **It is where you are from.  What you are made of.  The dark side--and the light**.  The finest sculptor cannot fashion a masterpiece from poor materials.  He must have something pure, something strong, something unbreakable, with which to work.  I have--you"

Further confirmation from TFA Visual Dictionary:

> **Having studied Jedi skills** as well as arcane dark side lore...

and his training with Snoke is mentioned as well:

> Kylo Ren is **the most gifted apprentice of Supreme Leader Snoke**... (of course, we can also see the same from film dialog)

Comment: Snoke is a Grey Jedi?

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay - more bluish-tinted :)

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` lol idk

Answer (score 2):

Learning to use the force is light or dark agnostic. To what ends and how you manipulate the the force are what distinguishes light from dark side.

Therefore, Ben's training began with Luke.

Comment: But did it continue with Snoke?

Answer (score 1):

We hear in conversations between a few characters that Kylo Ren was seduced to the dark side by Snoke, and led him to do the massacre of the Luke's Jedi students.

Comment: But did Snoke ever *train* him?