# Has Kylo Ren actually met Supreme Leader Snoke?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren, snoke

Inspired by these two questions:

[Why was the image of Supreme Leader Snoke not "scaled to fit our primitive screens"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126425/why-was-the-image-of-supreme-leader-snoke-not-scaled-to-fit-our-primitive-scree)

[Did Kylo Ren ever actually start training with Snoke?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114650/did-kylo-ren-ever-actually-start-training-with-snoke)

Do we know if Kylo has met Snoke in person? One would think if the relationship is akin to the Vader/Palpatine one, then they most certainly have. Is there any concrete evidence?

Comment: Good question, dunno. There's nothing in either novelisation, nor in the film itself that answers this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, as seen in *The Last Jedi*.

We see Ren (and Hux) in Snoke's chambers early on in the movie.

Later on,

> Ren returns to Snokes chambers with Rey. Snoke tasks Ren with killing Rey, but Ren kills Snoke instead, and the two temporarily join *forces* to take on Snokes elite praetorian guards.

Comment: and judging by the interaction it doesn't seem like it was the first Kylo was there. Good one picking up this old question to update it based on the new film!

Comment: @Skooba - Yes, you're absolutely correct. I would be shocked if it was the first time. It is however, the first time we actually have concrete proof of them meeting face to face.

Answer (score 4):

In the Legends book Darth Plagueis, Plagueis states that the most important information and the best training comes from one on one lessons between master and apprentice.  Not through other means like holocrons and transmissions.  Also in the movie Snoke recalls Kylo and says, "We must complete your training," suggesting that they have started and then halted to execute some plans.

The only problem with any of this is that I don't think Snoke is a Sith Lord so he may not adhere to the same rules.   As for hard concrete evidence, we will have to see.  Abrams hasn't said much.

> Sidious remained silent for a long moment. “Am I to be equally
>   distrustful of the lessons contained in Sith Holocrons?” “Not
>   distrustful,” Plagueis said gravely. “But holocrons contain knowledge
>   specific and idiosyncratic to each Sith who constructed them. Real
>   knowledge is passed by Master to apprentice in sessions such as this,
>   where nothing is codified or recorded—diluted—and thus it cannot be
>   forgotten. There will come a time when you may wish to consult the
>   holocrons of past Masters, but until then you would do better not to
>   be influenced by them. You must discover the dark side in your own
>   way, and perfect your power in your own fashion. All I can do in the
>   meantime is help to keep you from losing your way while we hide in
>   plain sight from the prying eyes of our enemies.”

Comment: *Darth Plagueis* is a different continuity to *The Force Awakens*.

Comment: @RogueJedi I thought Palpatine mentioned Plagueis by name in episode III?

Comment: No he is right, Darth Plagueis the novel is no longer canon with Disney's purchase of Lucas films.  Darth Plagueis the person is canon though.  What Sidious says in episode 3 is all true but the vast majority of the story is now legend.  Some of it is canonized in the novel Tarkin.  I just wanted to point out that traditionally master/apprentice relationships are face to face.

Comment: Ya this stack is awesome.  Thanks for the tip.  I edited it.